# In which software this 3D volume has been visualized?

Tags: python-2.7, vtk, itk, 3d-reconstruction, 3d-rendering

I read a paper and saw a very nice visualization of their 3D volume segmentation.
[This is the 3D visualization in the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHgcl.png)

Do you have any idea that what software they have used for 3d-reconstruction of the volume?

I have done the segmentation and would like to visualize it in python. Is there any shared code on GitHub or online that I can use it for visualization?

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/volume-rendering-with-python-and-vtk/)? Or [this](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/vtkVolumeRendering.html)? Or [this](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Examples/Medical/Python/Medical4.py)? Get VTK from [here](https://www.vtk.org/download/).